# How do I add a class to an element in jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a jQuery object with all child elements when I call

`var x = $('.myClass')`

I want to add a css class to `x[5]` element.How can I do this?

I tried `x[5].addClass('newClass');` But that didnt work.

Comment: `$(x[5]).addClass('newClass')` ... the values of x[n] are the elements, not jquery objects ... you could use DOM methods ... `x[5].classList.add('newClass')` - though classList is unsupported in IE9 or earlier

Comment: `$('elem').addClass('newClass');` 
Is `x` an array?

Comment: You should actually be using jQuery methods IMO, as in `x.eq(5).addClass('newClass')` etc.

Comment: @JaromandaX your answer worked too. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @sidx - as pointed out, if using jquery, makes far more sense to use jquery methods `x.eq(5).....`

Answer (score 1):

As `x` is a jQuery collection, you can use methods like `eq()`, `lt()`, `gt()` etc. instead of bracket notation.

Bracket notation accesses the underlying DOM nodes instead of the wrapped jQuery nodes you get when using jQuery's own methods, like this

```
x.eq(5).addClass('newClass')
```

Comment: `x.gt(5).addClass('newClass')` didnt work. But `eq` worked fine.

Comment: The `gt` and `lt` selectors means *"greater than"*, and *"lower than"*, and where just examples of jQuery methods that can be used to limit the collection directly. In this case as you only want one element, the one at index `5`, you should use `eq`.

Comment: I figured gt was greater than, actually I wanted to add a class to all elements whose index was greater than 5.